# Launching C++ on VSCode on Linux: PAUSED ON EXCEPTION received signal

Tags: multithreading, gdb, vscode-extensions

I have a multi-threaded (QT based) C++ application running on Linux.
After setting up VSCode with the C++ extension I can successfully attach the debugger to the running process and enjoy a reasonable debugging experience.

***HOWEVER***, If I try to Launch the application within VSCode, it starts up fine but at some point it pauses with the call stack showing PAUSED ON EXCEPTION coming from lower level libraries.
By clicking CONTINUE it stops again for similar reasons but in a different thread.

The call stack looks like this

[image: Call Stack]
How do I tell gdb to continue instead of stopping?

Thank you